# Generating a pdf using IText library in java doesnt work as expected

Tags: java, itext

I have this piece of code that make me somehow a latex formula in a image and display to a pdf.The first thing is i have a error  when i open the pdf file 109. and the first page with the formulas is not displayed at all.
the next ones is ok.
Any ideas? Thanks

```
 document.open();
                Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
                // We add one empty line
                addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
                // Lets write a big header
                preface.add(new Paragraph("Test Generat", catFont));

                addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
                document.add(preface);
            // Start a new page
           // document.newPage();
            for (int i = 0; i < intrebari.size(); i++) {

                TeXFormula formula = new TeXFormula("x=\\frac{-b \\pm \\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}");
                TeXIcon icon = formula
                        .createTeXIcon(TeXConstants.STYLE_DISPLAY, 20);

                // insert a border 
                icon.setInsets(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

                // now create an actual image of the rendered equation
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(icon.getIconWidth(),
                        icon.getIconHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
                Graphics2D g2 = image.createGraphics();
                g2.setColor(Color.white);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, icon.getIconWidth(), icon.getIconHeight());
                JLabel jl = new JLabel();
                jl.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0));
                icon.paintIcon(jl, g2, 0, 0);
                document.setPageSize(PageSize.A4);
                PdfContentByte pdfCB = new PdfContentByte(writer);
                try {

                    Image image1 = Image.getInstance(pdfCB, image, 1);
                    document.newPage();

                    Phrase p = new Phrase("quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.");

                    p.add(new Chunk(image1, 0, 0, true));
                    p.add("  ");
                    p.add(new Chunk(image1, 0, 0, true));
                    ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
                    ct.setSimpleColumn(new Rectangle(20, document.getPageSize().getWidth(), 400, 800));
                    ct.addText(p);
                    ct.go();
                    document.newPage();

                } catch (BadElementException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Utils.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            }

            document.newPage();

        }
```

Comment: Please provide the errormessage.

Comment: The error is "There was an error processing this page.There was a problem reading this document.(109)"

Comment: I bet that the problem doesn't occur when you don't add the image, which would mean that the culprit is the image. I can't reproduce the problem, because I don't have the `TeXFormula` class, but what happens is you add `g2.dispose()` before you use the `g2` object to paint the icon? Also: is that really the only way to create that image? Why don't you use iText's `PdfGraphics2D` object instead of using a `JLabel`?

Comment: If i use the `g2.dispose()` then my images aren't printed to pdf.

Comment: another way to create images,can you detail a bit more?or maybe give me one good example